# Scroll to top/bottom button error

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I want to add a scroll to top/bottom button on my blog. So I found this.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvHah/

**HTML**

```
<div class='button_up' id='button_up' style='display:none;'/>
<div class='button_down' id='button_down' style='display:none;'/>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {background:pink; height:2000px;}
 /* Up and Down Buttons with jQuery
----------------------------------------------- */
.button_down{
    padding:7px; /* Distance between the border and the icon */
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #CCC; /* Border Color */
    position:fixed;
    background: white url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sukwuViZaYY/T6rH15A8niI/AAAAAAAACeM/YErd0S8lPGA/s16/arrow_down.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    width:20px; /* Button's width */
    height:20px; /* Button's height */
    bottom:242px; /* Distance from the bottom */
    right:5px; /* Change right to left if you want the buttons on the left */
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}

.button_up{
    padding:7px; /* Distance between the border and the icon */
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #CCC; /* Border Color */
    position:fixed;
    background: white url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7zE5N9GdDUk/T6rH17KE6II/AAAAAAAACeQ/aEcKRyEhxsE/s16/arrow_up.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    width:20px; /* Button's width */
    height:20px; /* Button's height */
    bottom:280px; /* Distance from the bottom */
    right:5px; /* Change right to left if you want the buttons on the left */
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    opacity:0.7; 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function(){var special=jQuery.event.special,uid1='D'+(+new Date()),uid2='D'+(+new Date()+1);special.scrollstart={setup:function(){var timer,handler=function(evt){var _self=this,_args=arguments;if(timer){clearTimeout(timer)}else{evt.type='scrollstart';jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self,_args)}timer=setTimeout(function(){timer=null},special.scrollstop.latency)};jQuery(this).bind('scroll',handler).data(uid1,handler)},teardown:function(){jQuery(this).unbind('scroll',jQuery(this).data(uid1))}};special.scrollstop={latency:300,setup:function(){var timer,handler=function(evt){var _self=this,_args=arguments;if(timer){clearTimeout(timer)}timer=setTimeout(function(){timer=null;evt.type='scrollstop';jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self,_args)},special.scrollstop.latency)};jQuery(this).bind('scroll',handler).data(uid2,handler)},teardown:function(){jQuery(this).unbind('scroll',jQuery(this).data(uid2))}}})();

$(function() {
    var $elem = $('body');
    $('#button_up').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#button_down').fadeIn('slow'); 
    $(window).bind('scrollstart', function(){
    $('#button_up,#button_down').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.2'});
});
$(window).bind('scrollstop', function(){
    $('#button_up,#button_down').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
});
$('#button_down').click(
function (e) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
} );
$('#button_up').click(
function (e) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
} );});
```

This is exactly what I was looking for. But there is a problem. When you click on bottom button it works fine, takes me to the bottom of the page. But when it reaches the bottom, it automatically takes me to the top of the page. What seems to be the problem? Can someone fix the code.
Or anything similar to this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a mistake on closing your DIVs tags. Try this HTML Markup :

```
<div class='button_up' id='button_up' style='display:none;' ></div>
<div class='button_down' id='button_down' style='display:none;' ></div>
```

In fact, your first DIV (up) wasn't considered as closed, so your second div was "inside" up button, so two events were captured down and up.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t97Ee/)

Comment: OOps. I found it so I didn't even tried to look at the code myself. Thanks :)